# Upload ipa and apk after build to s3 using teamCity

Tags: android, ios, xcode, amazon-s3, teamcity

I would like to upload my `ipa` and `apk` to `s3 bucket` using `team city`...

My app builds with react native and for iOS Im using `Xcode` and for android I'm using `Gradle` and `visual studio code`

For example: I would like after I'm doing `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` in the cmd so the app builds for android and when it done to upload the apk which created to my s3 bucket using team city. (same with Xcode after pressing the play button)

I have been trying to find a good guide to explain me how to do it but I couldn't find a guide that will satisfy me...

I would like to get some help and to know my options

Thank you

Comment: react-native run-android doesn't build into .apk file. you have to run "cd android" && "./gradlew assembleRelease"  to build .apk file. I just want to know whether you have done with signing the apk step before helping you. Thanks

Comment: @DhivakarRagupathy hi thank you for the help..I was updating my question.. my app is already exist in the store and signed in..all I want to do is to store the apk/ipa in the s3 bucket of aws

Comment: Use the s3 external plug, it works for me and very east to use

Answer (score 0):

You can set up [an external S3 artifacts storage](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-artifacts-storage.html#ConfiguringArtifactsStorage-AmazonS3Support) in TeamCity and publish necessary files as artifacts in General build configuration settings. TeamCity will automatically publish data to the configured bucket at the end of the build.